# JavaScript file Not Minifying Correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to minify a JavaScript file for my website but this part of the code in the snippet is causing errors when it minifies.

```
//do not hide if click on the label object associated to the select
```

Do I need this part of the code or is it an important command for the code. If I do need it, do I need to add anything to it in order to minify correctly?

```js
 /* Hide all open selects */
 var jqTransformHideSelect = function(oTarget){
  var ulVisible = $('.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul:visible');
  ulVisible.each(function(){
   var oSelect = $(this).parents(".jqTransformSelectWrapper:first").find("select").get(0);
   //do not hide if click on the label object associated to the select
   if( !(oTarget && oSelect.oLabel && oSelect.oLabel.get(0) == oTarget.get(0)) ){$(this).hide();}
  });
 };
```

Comment: `//` is a single line comment. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a comment. You can remove it. Check out [this article on JavaScript comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6s6fab9k(v=vs.94).aspx).

Also, you can lint it to see if there are any issues. I linted it for you:

[image: lint]

Make sure you've included jQuery and all that good stuff.

Comment: ok thanks guys that's great. I deleted all the comments and minified myself as the minifies online were taking out code etc making not work. All done now though.